# MP4/h264 decoding library for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, h.264, mp4, decoder

I am looking for a mp4/h264 decoder for Windows Phone 8 which allows me to access the decoded video frame data (after I/P/B frame processing). Afaik Windows Phone 8 itself does not provide means to access the decoded h264 data for further processing.

Can you recommend a library which is prefereably written in C/C++, is plattform independent, and can be compiled on WP8? Both, free and commercial suggestions are welcome.

Regards,

Comment: There are several ways to achieve it. 1. Porting a java library to C# (ex: jcodec) or 2. Searching for existing ports. (Just a clue.) Or 3. Finding a simple c or c++ decoder (either from .mp4 or from a bitstream), and to ensure it will work as-is, start by compiling it in Win32, then on ARM as static dll, then in Windows Phone SDK as a Windows Phone Runtime Component.

Comment: As another comment, since I cannot add an answer: Almost --ANY-- C++ library can be compiled on Windows Phone. And platform independent libraries are more common than you think. It's more tricky when you have to deal with C89 vs C99, but otherwise, if you are working with a C++ solution, C++/CX is really useful.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [FFMpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) or [libav](http://www.libav.org).

Comment: Both are not ready (yet) for the VC/WP8 toolchain.